# How to make the .svc.cs or .svc.vb file visible in Solution Explorrer for a WCF project?

Tags: vb.net, wcf, visual-studio-2010, mercurial, visualhg

I have a solution that contains a WCF service project. In Solution Explorer only the MyService.svc file is shown, but on double clicking it the MyService.svc.vb file opens for editing. That is OK, but Visual HG (based on Mercurial) now doesn't show that the MyService.svc.vb file has changed and I cannot commit any changes without browsing to the Tortoise HG workbench. This is a possible cause for errors when merging code. So, how do I make the MyService.svc.vb file appear in Solution Explorer?

EDIT:
The problem seems to be limited to VB WCF projects. In C# there is an arrow before the .svc file that will show the svc.cs file when clicked. Bug?

Comment: With a WCF service project I get an arrow next to the .svc file that if I click shows the .cs file

Comment: @RichardBlewett I do not. The arrow does not appear in a VB WCF project. Have we hit on a bug here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to make this work is to click on the "Show All Files" Icon in Solution Explorer.

[image]

While I can't say with 100% certainty that the behavior difference between C# and VB.Net is "By Design" it almost certainly is.  There were very analogous decisions in other project types and likely the same decision was applied to WCF services.  The rationale behind it is that VB users don't want the clutter.

Comment: Thank you. I tried that before, but it did not seem to work. It seems that it does ;-) It may be by design, but it is not consistent with how, for example, xaml and xaml.vb files are handled in Solution Explorer.